# Why many in-car navigation systems choose to go through the city center?

Tags: routing, algorithm, navigation

Most of the in-car navigation systems I've been using prefer to select an itinerary that goes through the city center, rather than getting around. And this is the case while the "Fastest" (not "Shortest") route option is selected.

Of course, mathematically, the shortest path from A to B is a straight line. So even though a city is between A and B, the shortest path is going through the center of that city, distance wise.

But (besides traffic, that requires to get real-time data, and is not the point of this post) cities have usually traffic lights, lower speed limit etc... that increase significantly the time to travel from A to B.

So the question, that I've been wondering for some time, why do many in-car systems go through city centers

- Because even today's algorithms do not take into account the number of traffic lights to cross, city speed limits etc...?
- Because navigation systems have been "required" to get people do shopping etc... within cities?
- other reasons...

Comment: Is it possible, that the route is actually faster (and not only subjectively more "comfortable" to drive)? Can you provide an itinerary with both alternatives you have in mind as an example to support your question?

Comment: Question is about **in-car** navigation systems ; Google does better! Comparing, say, Google Maps with the in-car system, Google chooses the get-around route.

Comment: Yes, I understand the question. However a internet connection is not mandatory for using e.g. some kind of traffic data for calculating a perfect route, which means it can, in theory, also be used in a "traditional" in-car system. So imho it is not really possible to answer this question in general with one final answer, so you might specify the system(s) you are talking about, if this is possible.